# Intersymbol interference vs aliasing

Tags: digital-communications

I was trying to figure out if ISI in time domain is similar to aliasing in frequency domain?

Are these two phenomenon dual of each other?

It would be of great help if someone could explain this.

Comment: I think there is no relation between the two. Aliasing is happening when a signal is sampled (and restored). No sampling is needed to have ISI.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting thought, no doubt inspired by the similarity of the diagrams used to explain the two phenomena.

However, I don't see any way in which they could be considered duals of each other. Intersymbol interference is normally a linear, continuous-time phenomenon, while aliasing is associated strictly with sampled (quantized time) systems.

Comment: +1 I agree. ISI is a real effect related to long transmission lines with bad termination and several bit in flight. You can't change the effect by changing your observation instrument. The aliasing is a pure artifact of measuring instrument, and the effect can be eliminated by selecting a higher sampling rate.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for my lack of comprehensive signal processing knowledge, but I'd like to reflect on this interesting analogy. To be cautious, I'd rather use the broad term analogy, than duality or equivalency.  Shout-out to Noam Chomsky and Douglas Hofstadter!

If a waveform with length L is repeated (overlayed and added) by period R<L, its spectrum will be sampled with interval 1/R > 1/L (Fourier series).  The interference that occurs in the time domain is equivalent to undersampling in the frequency domain (lack of frequency resolution). In this sense, ISI (a kind of frequency undersampling) can be viewed as similar to aliasing (undersampling in time).

In practice, ISI is typically caused by dispersive or reflective phenomena of materials interacting with waves inside a channel. If ISI is purely due to dispersion, the phase spectrum is undersampled. If reflection, the amplitude spectrum.

Aliasing is a familiar challenge for time-domain samplers, which would require an anti-aliasing filter (AAF). The AAF mitigates signal corruption at the cost of loss of high-frequency information.

Frequency under-sampling is a challenge for frequency-domain spectrometers with low step-resolution (or perhaps resolution bandwidth, RBW).  It can be helped by convolving the spectrum with a Sinc function, which will mitigate signal corruption at the cost of losing 'late-time' information.

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing = take too sparsely samples and get some frequency components shifted in frequency to overlap . Take too sparse frequencies of a continuous signal spectrum and as a consequence get some time domain samples shifted in time to overlap. That causes intersymbol interference. So we at lest have a way to cause intersymbol interference which way is in dual relationship with aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

ISI results from energy storage. Aliasing needs no energy storage.

Answer (score 0):

**How they are similar:**

Both of them result in corruption of data, distortion in data. There is some overlapping present. Messed up frequencies and undesired time intervals are the keys for both.

**How they are different:**

Except for what I typed above, they are different in every sense. I somehow squeezed all the matching elements from both just because you were confused about their similarities and differences but **DO NOT RELATE THEM SO CLOSELY**.

I'm clarifying them more below. Hopefully it will help.

**Aliasing:**

Aliasing is a sampling related mishap. Occurs when a signal is undersampled than what Nyquist Rate suggests. Hence you'll not get the original signal back when you try to reconstruct it from samples.

**What does that mean in frequency domain?** Sampling frequency is less than the maximum frequency occurring in the signal.

**Means?** You get samples less frequently while signal changes more frequently.

**Result?** Loss in data in between the samples you've taken because signal has drastically changed during the time you wait too sample. **(Time domain definition)**

**ISI:**

ISI is a transmission related mishap. Occurs when more than one RIGHTEOUS SYMBOLS tend to distort eachothers' data. Here all the symbols contain desired information but their information is messed up because of time management. You have sent more symbols in a time less could be (and should be) transmitted.

**What does that mean in time domain?** Actual transmission time for a symbol is less than required transmission time.

**Means?** You are foisting more information in a a short span of time. No doubt there will be some INTERFERENCE in the bits of a symbol with that of another symbol.

**Result?** More frequent transfers in real however it is desired to transfer at some lower frequency. **(Frequency domain definition)**

In short:

**Aliasing** : Loss because of Laziness.

**ISI** : Haste makes Waste.

Aliasing is shorter frequency intervals, larger time spans. ISI is larger frequency acts, smaller time periods. In this way you may say that they form a time - frequency dual. But its just they are mathematical duals of eachother and its plain wrong to consider them as dual when you talk more logistically.